# AOSP: Build issue about timezone

Tags: android, build, android-source

I'm building AOSP. I have followed carrefully the requirements and the build instructions but I get a compilcation error saying:

> frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/timezone/RulesManagerService.java:50:
>   error: package libcore.timezone does not exist

I don't know how to fix this issue. Did I miss some settings about the **timezone**?
Thanks for your help

Here is the error log:

> java.jar -source 1.8 -target 1.8 -d
>   out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/services/core/services.core.unboosted/android_common/javac/classes
>   -s out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/services/core/services.core.unboosted/android_common/javac/anno
>   @out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/services/core/services.core.unboosted/android_common/javac/services.core.unboosted.jar.rsp
>   @out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/services/core/services.core.unboosted/android_common/javac/srcjars/list
>   ; fi ) && out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/soong_zip -jar -o
>   out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/services/core/services.core.unboosted/android_common/javac/services.core.unboosted.jar
>   -C out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/services/core/services.core.unboosted/android_common/javac/classes
>   -D out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/services/core/services.core.unboosted/android_common/javac/classes
>   frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/timezone/RulesManagerService.java:50:
>   error: package libcore.timezone does not exist import
>   libcore.timezone.TzDataSetVersion;
>                          ^ frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/timezone/RulesManagerService.java:70:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>                       TzDataSetVersion.currentFormatMajorVersion(),
>                       ^   symbol:   variable TzDataSetVersion   location: class RulesManagerService
>   frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/timezone/RulesManagerService.java:71:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>                       TzDataSetVersion.currentFormatMinorVersion());
>                       ^   symbol:   variable TzDataSetVersion   location: class RulesManagerService 3 errors [ 92% 108190/116405]
>   //frameworks/base:api-stubs-docs Metalava [common]
>
> /local/android_source/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/MediaDrm.java:1207:
>   warning: Returning unexpected constant SECURITY_LEVEL_MAX; is
>   @SecurityLevel missing this constant? Expected one of
>   SECURITY_LEVEL_UNKNOWN, SECURITY_LEVEL_SW_SECURE_CRYPTO,
>   SECURITY_LEVEL_SW_SECURE_DECODE, SECURITY_LEVEL_HW_SECURE_CRYPTO,
>   SECURITY_LEVEL_HW_SECURE_DECODE, SECURITY_LEVEL_HW_SECURE_ALL
>   [ReturningUnexpectedConstant] [ 92% 108191/116405]
>   //frameworks/base:hiddenapi-lists-docs Metalava [common]
>
> /local/android_source/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/MediaDrm.java:1207:
>   warning: Returning unexpected constant SECURITY_LEVEL_MAX; is
>   @SecurityLevel missing this constant? Expected one of
>   SECURITY_LEVEL_UNKNOWN, SECURITY_LEVEL_SW_SECURE_CRYPTO,
>   SECURITY_LEVEL_SW_SECURE_DECODE, SECURITY_LEVEL_HW_SECURE_CRYPTO,
>   SECURITY_LEVEL_HW_SECURE_DECODE, SECURITY_LEVEL_HW_SECURE_ALL
>   [ReturningUnexpectedConstant] [ 92% 108192/116405]
>   //frameworks/base:system-api-stubs-docs Metalava [common]
>
> /local/android_source/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/MediaDrm.java:1207:
>   warning: Returning unexpected constant SECURITY_LEVEL_MAX; is
>   @SecurityLevel missing this constant? Expected one of
>   SECURITY_LEVEL_UNKNOWN, SECURITY_LEVEL_SW_SECURE_CRYPTO,
>   SECURITY_LEVEL_SW_SECURE_DECODE, SECURITY_LEVEL_HW_SECURE_CRYPTO,
>   SECURITY_LEVEL_HW_SECURE_DECODE, SECURITY_LEVEL_HW_SECURE_ALL
>   [ReturningUnexpectedConstant] 20:45:17 ninja failed with: exit status
>   1
>
> failed to build some targets (10:03:02 (hh:mm:ss))

Answer (score 0):

I have pulled the latest change with "repo sync", rebuild all and I didn't get this error. I don't know what was wrong the first time but the issue can be closed.